# Typeorm composite key: query only newest version

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have a composite primary key of uuid and version.
What would be the best practice of querying only the newest version of all entities matching a certain where clause? I probably need some kind of distinct clause ... is this possible using active record pattern?

```js
   // returns all articles ordered by version, but I need only the newest version of each Article 
   Article.find({
      where: {
        company: '35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076',
        status: 'approved',
      },
      order: {
        version: 'DESC',
      });
```

Table looks like:

| uuid | version | status | company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50ea6422-f56e-45e2-... | 1 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 8e6d646b-4772-47c6-... | 1 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 93b06cef-0d94-493b-... | 1 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 0094d9da-1768-4b8b-... | 1 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 0094d9da-1768-4b8b-... | 0 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 3bf2a3b3-e201-4bb1-... | 0 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| 875c1145-a793-4243-... | 0 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |
| a2c63577-2bff-4104-... | 0 | APPROVED | 35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited due to misreading the question*

What you are trying to achieve is "select latest" or "select highest" for each entity. This can be done, but the solution may become Database dependent or be inefficient.

The query you need to execute (assuming you are using a SQL DB) is:

```sql
select a.*
from articles a
inner join (
    select uuid, max(version) as version
    from articles group by uuid
) b
on a.uuid = b.uuid and a.version = b.version;
```

This can be done in TypeORM (with Active Record pattern):

```js
@Entity()
export class Article extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    uuid: string;
    @PrimaryColumn()
    version: number;
    @Column()
    status: string;
    @Column()
    company: string;

    static latest(
        where?: Brackets | string | ObjectLiteral | ObjectLiteral[],
        parameters?: ObjectLiteral
    ): Promise<Article[] | undefined> {
        // Pivot table
        let pvt = this.createQueryBuilder('pvt')
            .select(['uuid', 'max(version) as version'])
            .groupBy('uuid');
        if (where) pvt = pvt.where(where, parameters);
        // Select
        return this.createQueryBuilder('art')
            .innerJoin(
                `(${pvt.getQuery()})`,
                'pvt',
                'art.uuid = pvt.uuid and art.version = pvt.version'
            )
            .setParameters(pvt.getParameters())
            .getMany();
    }
}
```

And used as follows:

```js
Article.latest({
    company: '35fccfba-b4f8-4393-b211-c258d0a79076',
    status: 'approved',
})
```

#### Other solutions

An approach that is often neglected is to **change data structure according to your query load**.

The proposed solution becomes messy as complexity grows. This is why I would suggest you use a different approach. For example, keep a table that holds only the latest version and another that keeps all (or all except the last) versions. *Hence, bend the data structure to better fit your query load.*

Comment: this would return only ONE article but I need the latest version of all articles from the company.

Comment: @KarlAdler sorry I mesread. The answer has been fixed ;)

Comment: thanks for the update and also for the hint. You might be right about changing the data structure a bit, but two tables are not an option, since the latest article might not be the latest approved one. But maybe I just add a flag for the "current-used" and query for this.

Comment: @KarlAdler yep, that would work as well. If your structure is more complicated, maintaining an indexed flag solves your issue. But you need to be extra careful (or add a constraint to enforce only one `uuid` has the flag set)